# How to execute shell script via crontab?

Tags: linux, crontab

I have a `notify.sh` script that looks like:

```
notify-send "hi welcome"
```

My crontab notification for 2 PM:

```
0 14 * * * home/hacks/notify.sh
```

However, this doesn't work. What is the problem?

Answer (score 50):

Your script is missing a #! line at the start, which is the magic interpreted by the kernel to say which command interpreter is to be used for the script.

Make it look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
notify-send "hi welcome"
```

and make sure the script is executable:

```
ls -l home/hacks/notify.sh
chmod +x home/hacks/notify.sh
ls -l home/hacks/notify.sh
```

Also, since you're asking for this to happen just once a day, is the timezone of the crontab the same as your own timezone?  You might find this happening at 2pm GMT.

Comment: +1 This answer is awesome - particularly noting the point about the script needs to being executable!  Thanks!

Comment: Very subtle explanation. My upvote

Answer (score 26):

Making crontab running is easy only . Here I am going to say how to run crontab jobs.  It is useful for anyone who is stuck on crontab.

```
*/1 * * * * cd /home/hacks && sh notify.sh
```

To make the script executable, we have to do:

```
chmod +x home/hacks/notify.sh
```

Here i run this script for every one minute ...
By doing below script, you can write it in a log file to find whether its working

write log

```
*/1 * * * * cd /home/hacks && sh notify.sh>>test.log
```

send mail

```
*/1 * * * * cd /home/hacks && sh notify.sh>>test.log | mail -s "Hi this is example" user@domain.com
```

Comment: isnt that "*/1 * * * * sh /home/hacks/notify.sh" will also work ?

Answer (score 5):

4 hypothesis:

- the cron daemon is not running (do a `ps axfww | grep cron` and check)
- the notify-send is trying to send output to a terminal, or an X session -- but it is ran from within the `cron` environment and it does not know "who to talk to", so to speak.
- your script is not executable
- the `home/` path in the crontab script is relative to the user the scripts gets executed as. Try using the full path

Answer (score 1):

Add `export DISPLAY=:0` above the notify-send line in your script. This addresses lornezog's second point.

Answer (score 0):

First of All, we need to edit the crontab with Command `crontab -e`and than Inside this `Crontab` add the Path of Executable script and in your Case like this
 `* 14 * * * home/hacks/notify.sh >/dev/null 2>&1` .

**Start /Stop / restart  cron service**

- `/etc/init.d/crond start /stop / restart`
- `service crond start /stop /restart`
- `systemctl stop crond.service`

systemctl stop crond.service

Comment: you shouldn't need to restart according to answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193788/restarting-cron-after-changing-crontab-file

Answer (score -1):

You have to open crontab by the following command:

```
crontab -u username -e (to edit) -l(to list) -r(to remove) 10(minutes) 8-15(hours) *(Day of month) *(month) 1,3,5(days of week) /path/to/script/script_name.sh
```

This will run your script once an hour from 8AM-3PM at 10 minutes past the hour every Monday, Wednesday and Friday.

Answer (score -3):

quite simple, add following line at bottom of the crontab file via:
`sudo nano /etc/crontab`

`@reboot  root   cd /home/pi/node-sonos-http-api && npm start &`

Comment: This does not seem to be an answer to the question.